# Run a Javascript file (server-side, using Node.js) from the browser / internet

Tags: linux, redhat, ip, node.js

I've got a javascript file on a RHEL server, which I can run (when communicating through console / SSH to the server) using 'node script.js'.

However, I'd like a user to be able to activate the script by visiting a URL.

I tried actually running a http server in script.js, but couldn't figure out what to put as the IP (after all, it's on an existing linux server! I can already publicly read the script.js file contents through the browser), using this template;

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I've no idea what IP I'd specify for the server, or what URL I'd launch the script with;
obviously I'm lacking some pretty important conceptual understandings of what exactly Node.js does.

So; how would I do this?
Try to emulate the http server thing above, or somehow access the command prompt via a server-side script, in PHP or something?

Thanks

Comment: (if you're interested, I'm using Node.js because my program depends highly on concurrency, and I've reached big headaches in installing pthreads for PHP because I can't Yum php-devel - which is needed to allow the PECL installation of pthreads to use 'phpize()' - because Yum has no base repo because something something registration something I'm going to cut off all my limbs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until a better solution reveals itself, I'm having a (publicly accessible) PHP script launch the javascript by executing a shell command

```
exec("node javascript.js params");
```